# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcodec2 Error installing pycodec2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, codec

I am unable to install `pycodec2`. I first git cloned the [pycodec2](https://github.com/gregorias/pycodec2/) repo. Then cloned and installed codec2 repo inside it. I had to edit a few paths in pycodec2, but after so much tinkering I am unable to get the pycodec2 running. Does anybody have experience installing pycodec2 and can share the steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install either the codec2 libraries, and/or the development files, depending on whether or not it is using them to run, or to compile.

On Ubuntu you can achieve this with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcodec2 libcodec2-dev
```

Comment: I installed it using `sudo apt-get install libcodec2-0.7 libcodec2-dev` 

I missed `make install` command earlier. Now I am able to `import pycodec2`. However, `pycodec2.Codec2(1200)` throws `AttributeError: module 'pycodec2' has no attribute 'Codec2'`

Answer (score 0):

i have installed the pycodec2 successfully on ubuntu 20.04!

```
1. sudo apt install libcodec2-dev
2. sudo apt install codec2 
# or install codec2 as officer website.
3. pip install pycodec2
```